# Create XML file based on Input values

Tags: javascript, xml, xml-parsing, xmlhttprequest

So, I need a script that takes **All** the form data in the URL and creates, or changes the existing nodes of an XML File.

I have done some research and found this:

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else {// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

xmlhttp.open("GET","page1.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;

function addElement() {
    var rootElement = document.documentElement;      
    var name = document.getElementById('namefield').value;
    var title = document.getElementById('titlefield').value;
    var phone = document.getElementById('phonefield').value;
    var email = document.getElementById('emailfield').value;

    /* create employee element*/
    var newEmployee = document.createElement('employee');

    /* create child elements and text values and append one by one */
    var newName = document.createElement('name');
    var newNameText = document.createTextNode(name);
    newName.appendChild(newNameText);
    newEmployee.appendChild(newName);

    var newTitle = document.createElement('title');
    var newTitleText = document.createTextNode(title);
    newTitle.appendChild(newTitleText);
    newEmployee.appendChild(newTitle);

    var newPhone = document.createElement('phone');
    var newPhoneText = document.createTextNode(phone);
    newPhone.appendChild(newPhoneText);
    newEmployee.appendChild(newPhone);

    var newEmail = document.createElement('email');
    var newEmailText = document.createTextNode(email);
    newEmail.appendChild(newEmailText);
    newEmployee.appendChild(newEmail);

    /* append completed record to the document */
    rootElement.appendChild(newEmployee);
    xmlDoc.save("page1.xml")
}
```

The only problem is the possible form data that the url could have could, or could **not** be there and I'm not sure how the script will respond to that, I'm not a wiz at how JavaScript creates XML and writes it, changes it, and I also need to know if this will update it.

This is a sample of what the XML should look like: *(I'm going to change the script to fit this in the future)*

```
<XML stuff>
    <document>
        <docname>My Document</docname>
        <text>Text</text>
        and so on...
    </document>
```

Comment: You need to use `if` statements.

Comment: can you explain more on what you mean? @SLaks